# Fill in the permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

From this cayley table[image]

$$T_d: G \to G$$ is defined by $$T_d(x)=dx$$, fill in the permutation

$$T_d=\begin{bmatrix}1&a&b&c&d&e&f&g\\?&?&?&?&?&?&?&?\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it just {d,ad,bd,cd,d^2,ed,fd,gd}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, note that this group isn't abelian; da=e, but ad=g, so the second row of the permutation should be (d,da,db,dc,d^2,de,df,dg), based on the definition you gave of the permutation. Of course, to simplify your answer, you would go through the Cayley table and replace each product with the element to which it is equal. Note that when you use a Cayley table, the row index is on the left, and the column index is on the right, e.g. for da, you would look at the row indexed d and the column indexed a and find the element at that column and row.

Answer (score 1):

The entries are literally just the row of the cayley table of d. Do you see why?